# Internet via on-board Ethernet card and Ethernet USB adapter does not work

Tags: computer-hardware

My desktop computer is connected to the internet via an Ethernet cable and a few days back the internet has stopped working. After making sure it was not the cable, I purchased an Ethernet USB adapter, but still no connection. The cable and adapter do work with the laptop, though. I'm thinking of buying a network card, not sure though that it will work. If the on-board Ethernet card and the Ethernet adapter do not work, it might have to do with the motherboard. Would you advise against buying the Ethernet network card?

Comment: Figure out what's wrong first. Check your bios settings to rule out having disabled something there. I suggest you boot your desktop from a "live cd" (I guess it's usb these days) to rule out software.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do have the internet connection when I use the "live cd". So, what's the next step to having the internet back without using the cd?

Comment: If the live cd works, it's not hardware and unlikely to be a bios issue.  One way that would likely work is reinstalling your Operating System from scratch and wiping everything out.  It's usually more aggressive than needed.  Somewhere in your system, there is a setting or maybe a faulty driver or corrupt OS file.  What is your operating system?  Start at common settings - ip, subnet, gateway settings...

Comment: My desktop runs on Ubuntu. What am I supposed to do with IP, subnet  and gateway settings?

Comment: Set them to what they are when things are working. (Dhcp enabled? Etc).  There are also specific config services related to internet that you may wish to compare to those on the live cd.  Old way was ifconfig...  i suspect this belongs in https://askubuntu.com/ now.  Edit your livecd stuff into the question, and it may be possible to migrate.